# Barcode scanner with a rectangular box using MLkit library in Android

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, firebase-mlkit

How to create a rectangular box that scan barcode which falls inside the box only using **MLKit** library in android.

By the default example given by MLKit GitHub, it scans the barcode from the entire screen. My use case is something similar like **scandit** library which scan only inside the given area of the box.

TIA

Comment: Wrote an article for just about that. For future reference: https://medium.com/@saiful103a/scan-barcode-only-when-they-are-inside-a-specific-area-of-the-preview-android-fcf8e02404d7